# dbx databricks deploy named properties

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-dbx

Can anyone provide me a link to an example of using named properties in dbx. The documentation mentions an example of a .json file,

https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/named_properties.html

but it does not mention how we can invoke this file with sample variables. Do I need to write python code to have a file containing these variables?

I have two enviornments and I want to pass on different variables to the deployment.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent way to passing var is by using the [--jinja-variables-file](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/jinja2_support.html#variable-file) since dbx 0.6.6.
And do not use the [env vars](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/jinja2_support.html#environment-variables), it's not jinja standard.

Answer (score 0):

author of `dbx` here.

With latest 0.7.0 update we fully support passing both environment variables and variables from file.

Please check:

- https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/jinja_support/
  for details